# Throw exception after reaching max attempts in resilience4j-retry

Tags: groovy, retry-logic, resilience4j

How I can throw an exception when maximum number of retries is reached.
In my case when `Response` has other code than 200 I would like to throw exception.

```
Retry retry = RetryRegistry.of(
  RetryConfig.<Response> custom()
    .retryOnResult({ it.statusCode() != 200 })
    .build())
  .retry("my-retry")


Response response = Retry.decorateSupplier(retry, { foo.bar() }).get()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can wrap your code and throw an exception when the HTTP code is not 200.

For example in Java code:

```
Supplier<Response> supplier= () -> foo.bar();
Supplier<String> supplierWithResultHandling = SupplierUtils.andThen(supplier, result -> {
   if (result.statusCode().is4xxClientError()) {
      throw new HttpClientErrorException(result.statusCode());
   } else if (result.statusCode().is5xxServerError())  {
      throw new HttpServerErrorException(result.statusCode());
   }
  return result;
});

Response response = retry.executeSupplier(supplierWithResultHandling);
```

Comment: How do I do this if I am using spring boot annotations?